# How to add ShortCut Keys to Submenus in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add Shortcut keys like Ctrl+O to submenus. The code which i am using:

```
<Menu>
       <MenuItem Header="_File" InputGestureText="alt+f">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" />    
       </MenuItem> 
</Menu>
```

When I add InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" on Open Menu Item then it is not working. Instead of working it is showing(Ctrl+O) along with Open text in menu Item while running.

Can you please provide any solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This property does not associate the input gesture with the menu item;
>   it simply adds text to the menu item. The application must handle the
>   user's input to carry out the action. For information on how to
>   associate a command with a menu item, see [Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.command(v=vs.110).aspx).